# Как в TSQL сконвертировать время заданное в виде строки с timezone в datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как в TSQL сконвертировать время заданное в виде строки с timezone в datetime?

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2006-12-12T23:45:12.000-08:00', 127)

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: А приведенный  SELECT равзе не минимальный пример ?   Мне нужна, чтобы указанная строка заработала.  По документации она должна работать, потому что в примере дата и время указанны в нужном формате.

Comment: Это должно быть ## 1-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение.

SQL Server 2016 и более поздние версии.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @var DATETIMEOFFSET(3) = '2006-12-12T23:45:12.000-08:00';
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT @var AS [Before]
    , CAST(@var AS DATETIME) AS [After]
    , @var AT TIME ZONE 'Russian Standard Time' AS [Local]
    , CAST(@var AT TIME ZONE 'Russian Standard Time' AS DATETIME) AS [LocalDateTime];

SELECT * FROM sys.time_zone_info
ORDER BY name;

SELECT @@VERSION;
```

Comment: Перечитал документацию и посмотрел пример и не совсем разобрался.  К примеру у меня локальное время gmt +02:00. В файле приходит запись c Time Zone -08:00. Я хочу перевести время из тайм зоны указанной в файле, в локальное. По идее я сначала должен привести время в GMT , а потом добавить +02:00. По текущему примеру строка просто перевеодиться в тип дата и время и при этом игнорируется timezone . Верно ?

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, Я обновил ответ.